# Red5: Playing subsequent videos with mp4 playlist

Tags: mp4, red5, playlist

Hi i just create an mp4 playlist application for red5 but i cannot figure out how to make the second and/or subsequent videos automatically play once the first clip has end.

Comment: How are you playing each video?